# Why is it necessary to write 0E5h in an Assembler code

Tags: assembly

Why is it necessary to write `0E5h` in assembly code instead of `E5h` for a one byte number containing only two hex positions?

Comment: Which assembler are you using?

Comment: I am using 8086 assembler.

Comment: Not which machine language target, I meant which assembler.  (e.g. YASM vs. GNU as.)  Although I did guess you were using MASM/NASM/YASM syntax for x86.  GNU as (in the default AT&T syntax mode) uses `test $0xE5, %eax` for an immediate constant, or `.byte 0xE5` for data.

Comment: But which one *exactly*. Do you think that the machine code & behaviour determines what the assembler or any other language looks like? Granted that frequently the manufacturer supplies an assembler. But googling '8086 assembly language programming' leads to wiki 'x86 assembly language' which says 'x86 assembly language has two main syntax branches: Intel syntax, originally used for documentation of the x86 platform, and AT&T syntax.' Always just be clear about all aspects of your context.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because `E5h` is a valid symbol name.

Comment: Exactly: to distinguish it from a symbol, which may not begin with a numeral.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language, and frequently this sort of decision is simply arbitrary although one of a cluster of related & interacting arbitary decisions, but probably the 0 is an indicator that the token is a literal number, rather than a name starting with E.